# Use cell value to specify another cell location

Tags: excel

I am building a dashboard in Excel, and pulling values from an OPC connection, but am struggling using a cell value to specify a location of another cell.

I have 3 sheets,

- 'LiveData' which reads values from an OPC connection
- 'Descriptions' which is the descriptions for different values
- 'Main' which is the dashboard

I want to read the value of LiveData!A1 (which is an integer) add 1 to that number, then use that number on 'Main' to make a specific cell's contents equal Descriptions!B(That Number)

The SAP tool I am using does not allow for vba or the address function.

Comment: Can you use the Indirect() function?

Comment: Compiling with Indirect also give me the same warning of it not being supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non volatile option is to use INDEX():

```
=INDEX(Descriptions!B:B,LiveData!A1+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for `=Indirect()`. `Indirect()` takes in a cell address as a string, and treats that string as the actual address.

Something like:

```
 =Indirect("Descriptions!B" & (LiveData!A1 +1))
```

Which will get the number from `LiveData!A1`, add one to it, then concatenate that number to the string `"Descriptions!B"`. `Indirect()` will then go get the value at that cell in `Descriptions` tab.